# Changing elements in a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

What I'm trying to do is generate a 15x15 square of "-" and accept a user input coordinate which will then replace the "-" with a "x" currently my program is just printing a vertical line of "-"

```
import java.util.*;
public class GameOfLife
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] boardList = new int[15][15];
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("1 - Add a being \n 2 - Show current board \n 3 - Show next generation \n 4 - Clear board \n 5 - Add preload pattern \n 6 - Exit");
            int choice = Integer.parseInt(myScanner.nextLine());
            if (choice == 1)
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the x coordinate: ");
                String answer = myScanner.nextLine();
                int xCoordinate = Integer.parseInt(answer);
                System.out.print("Enter the y coordinate: ");
                String answer2 = myScanner.nextLine();
                int yCoordinate = Integer.parseInt(answer2);
                for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
                {
                    for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                    {
                        if(xCoordinate == i)
                        {
                            if(yCoordinate == j)
                            {
                                System.out.printf("x", boardList[i][j]);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        System.out.printf("-", boardList[i][j]);
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you understand by `System.out.printf("x", boardList[i][j]);`.

Comment: where is while of do loop.

Comment: I used `System.out.printf` to get it to print earlier without trying to add coordinates in

Comment: The while for the do loop is down later in my choice 6.  I didn't feel like it was necessary to add it in because it didn't pertain to the error

Comment: it seems like your mixing up code intended to assign values to `boardlist` and code that is intended to print `boardlist`. The way it is now, `boardlist` is not used for anything at all.

Comment: `System.out.println();` belongs after next `}`. Then you get matrix instead of vertical line

Answer (score 2):

here you have , this works ... u need to put `System.out.println();` outside inner loop as well as put

```
if(xCoordinate == i){
  if(yCoordinate == j){
```

to one condition ...

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[][] boardList = new int[15][15];
            Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean done = true;
            do {
                System.out
                        .println("1 - Add a being \n 2 - Show current board \n 3 - Show next generation \n 4 - Clear board \n 5 - Add preload pattern \n 6 - Exit");
                int choice = Integer.parseInt(myScanner.nextLine());
                if (choice == 1) {
                    System.out.print("Enter the x coordinate: ");
                    String answer = myScanner.nextLine();
                    int xCoordinate = Integer.parseInt(answer);
                    System.out.print("Enter the y coordinate: ");
                    String answer2 = myScanner.nextLine();
                    int yCoordinate = Integer.parseInt(answer2);
                    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
                            if (xCoordinate == i && yCoordinate == j) {
                                System.out.printf("x", boardList[i][j]);
                            } else
                                System.out.printf("-", boardList[i][j]);
                        }
                        System.out.println();
                    }
                }
            } while (done);

        }
```

**//EDIT** note that i changed `done` to true just to demonstrate that it works ...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
    {
        if(xCoordinate == i && yCoordinate==j)
            System.out.printf("x", boardList[i][j]);
        else
            System.out.printf("-", boardList[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

You need to print the new line after you finish printing a whole row first

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, You want a two dimensional array initialized with '-', to do so you could do

```
int[][] boardList = new int[15][15];

for (int row = 0; row < 15; row ++)
    for (int col = 0; col < 15; col++)
        boardList[row][col] = '-';
```

And then, once you store the user data in `xCoordinate` and `Ycoordinate`, you simple do:

```
boardList[xCoordinate][Ycoordinate] = 'x';
```

Comment: boardlist is an int[][], not a char[][]

Comment: @matrixugly ups, I get confused when he said a 15x15 square of "-". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class StackOverflow 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] boardList = new int[15][15];
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;
        System.out.println("1 - Add a being \n 2 - Show current board \n 3 - Show next generation \n 4 - Clear board \n 5 - Add preload pattern \n 6 - Exit");
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(myScanner.nextLine());
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the x coordinate: ");
            String answer = myScanner.nextLine();
            int xCoordinate = Integer.parseInt(answer);
            System.out.print("Enter the y coordinate: ");
            String answer2 = myScanner.nextLine();
            int yCoordinate = Integer.parseInt(answer2);
            for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                {
                    if(xCoordinate == i)
                    {
                        if(yCoordinate == j)
                        {
                            System.out.printf("x", boardList[i][j]);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.printf("-", boardList[i][j]);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.printf("-", boardList[i][j]);
                    }

                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```